# Google analytics (UA) keeps counting checkout page as direct visit - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have a website I'm working on that's running on Wordpress and using woocommerce for the ecommerce. When I go to the my GA Universal analytics account and navigate to Site Content > Landing Pages ,  I keep notices "/checkout/order-received/###"  (### Denotes order ID) as being counted as direct visit (landed visits) to the website. Which means after the user pays and gets redirected to the thank you page, they are counted both as a new visit and as a conversion.
That means

- double counting the conversion
- counting thank you page visit as new visit

Does anyone know what could be causing this and how I could solve it?
[image]

Comment: Is thank you page and checkout on a different domain? Is there a different domain involved in the user journey?

Comment: Yes @BNazaruk thank you page and checkout are both on the same domain

Comment: If the whole user journey fits into one domain, then you'd have to do some actual debugging. Go to the site, start browsing it and pay attention to the `collect` network calls. Look for oddities and anomalies there.